# Exchange 2016 CLI does not accept Pipeline command of moving all arbitration mailboxes

Tags: powershell, pipeline, exchange-server

I follow guide on the Internet to move all mailboxes to another database.
The guide states that I need to move all arbitration mailboxes before user mailboxes and give below command

```
Get-Mailbox -Arbitration | New-MoveRequest -TargetDatabase MDB3
```

However, when I ran the command, it returns error:

```
The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline
input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft Exchange:PSObject) [New-MoveRequest], ParameterBindingExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,New-MoveRequest
    + PSComputerName        : ex-mbx5.testdomain.lca
```

I am running Exchange 2016 and 2010 (current in upgrading process).

Please kindly help

Comment: This is less of a programming problem and more system administration. You would probably do better asking on [SF]

Comment: The Identity parameter (`-Identity`) is the only one accepting pipeline input for [`New-MoveRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-moverequest?view=exchange-ps#-identity) cmdlet…

Comment: Maybe `Get-Mailbox -Arbitration | Forech-Object { $_.MailboxID | New-MoveRequest -TargetDatabase MDB3}`? (Not sure about property name `MailboxID`). Maybe `Get-Mailbox -Arbitration | Forech-Object { $_ | New-MoveRequest -TargetDatabase MDB3}` could suffice?

Comment: See examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-moverequest?view=exchange-ps#examples

Comment: @JosefZ : Not true. From Microsoft learn website, there is example below which take all mailboxes from 1st command and pipeline to second command: Get-Mailbox -Database DB01 | New-MoveRequest -TargetDatabase DB02 -BatchName "DB01toDB02"